# Send multiple attachments with Outlook, success but failiure

Tags: c#, outlook

The following code is ment to create an e-mail and attach the one or multiple attachemnts. So far the code does just that with success, but it also creates the equal amount of e-mails with the right amount of attachments in each of them. I.e. with three attachments it creates three e-mails all with the three attachments in each of them.

```
private void SendMail(List<string> paths)
        {
            DateTime defDt = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(3);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
            mailItem.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

            mailItem.GetInspector.Activate();
            var signature = mailItem.HTMLBody;
            mailItem.HTMLBody = signature;
            foreach (string u in paths)
            {
                mailItem.Attachments.Add(u);
            }
            mailItem.DeferredDeliveryTime = defDt;
            mailItem.Display(mailItem);

        }
```

Why does it behave like this? There are no foreach loop besides the one for adding the multiple attachments. When firing with one attachment the error doesn't show (probably since it i creating just one e-mail with one attachment as excpected). Any thoughts from this great community?

Comment: What happens if you comment out the whole `foreach` loop? Also, have you tried stepping through line-by-line? Is there any possibility this code is getting called multiple times by whatever's calling it?

Comment: Thank you! Didn't check ealier in the code and it was cought in a foreach loop calling it, så the code presented was not the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was called in a foreach loop earlier in the code. The code presented works as expected.